# RAM efficient multiplication of large matrices - running out of RAM in R

Tags: r, network-programming, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

I want to multiply a large matrix by its transpose to create an adjacency matrix (dimension: 1,7 Mio * 1,700, binary =0/1 entries). The matrix will result into a large matrix 1,7 Mio. * 1,7 Mio.., which is moderately sparse. Values are numbers between 1-50.

I have tried multiple approaches in R and Python, with high performance servers of up to 250 GB RAM, but I simply cannot get it to work. Thus, any tips on approaches that could work a highly appreciated

I am primarily working in R, I have tried the following already:

1. igraph package 
       routes_igraph <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices = nodes, 
       directed = TRUE)
2. Manual matrix multiplication 
       adjacency_matrix <- t(bipartite_matrix_s) %*% bipartite_matrix_s
3. "matrix" sparse matrix multiplication: Even on 250 GB RAM server, this creates the error: address 0x2ad6b3385000, cause 'memory not mapped'. It works for same dataset with smaller number of entries, so this should be a RAM problem. (incidence_matrix = 1,7 Mio * 1,700),

   ```
   bipartite_matrix_s <- as_incidence_matrix(y, sparse = TRUE) #(WORKS)
   adjacency_matrix <- tcrossprod(t(bipartite_matrix_s)) #(CRASHES)
   ```

"blockmatrix" multiplication --> this performs stepwise multiplication, which works fine, but somehow also saves the entire matrix (cannot allocate memory of 2,500 RAM)

```
    library(blockmatrix)
    edges <- blockmatmult(t(bipartite_matrix_s), bipartite_matrix_s)
    edgelist <- cbind(test_blockmult)
```

I am running out of ideas here, what could be ways to solve this?

Comment: The Matrix package has a sparse matrix `crossprod` method.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck : thanks for the reply! Am I not already using this functionality with specifying sparse = TRUE in the incidence_matrix function?